# PHP Namespaces have reverse slashes loading classes

Tags: php, class

I have 2 programs : 
1) index.php - (uses Jaspersoft\Client\Client)
2) autoload.dist.php - (tries to autoload Client class)

PROBLEM: The autoloader tries to load the Client.php like this :

> /var/www/html/REST/src/Jaspersoft\Client\Client.php

PLEASE NOTICE THE BACKSLASHES -- SHOULD I JUST STRING REPLACE THE BACK SLASHES TO SLASHES????

```
<?php

/*************
 * index.php
 *************/

// Mount the class autoloader
require_once "autoload.dist.php";

use Jaspersoft\Client\Client;

$c = new Client(
            "http://ladoodah.com:8080/jasperserver",
            "jasperadmin",
            "jasperadmin",
            ""
        );

$info = $c->serverInfo();

print_r($info);         

?>
```

> 

```
<?php

/*************
 * autoload.dist.php
 *************/

 define("JASPERCLIENT_ROOT", __DIR__ . "/src/");

 spl_autoload_register(function($class) {

 $location = JASPERCLIENT_ROOT . $class . '.php';

 if(!is_readable($location)) {
   return;
 }

 require_once $location;

 });
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a big deal. PHP is smart enough to handle the `\` slashes into the correct path format for the file system it lives on. However, if you feel the need to "fix" it, you could change the autoloader function:

```
<?php

/*************
 * autoload.dist.php
 *************/

 define("JASPERCLIENT_ROOT", __DIR__ . "/src/");

 spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
 $split = explode('\\', $class);
 $location = JASPERCLIENT_ROOT . implode('/', $split) . '.php';

 if(!is_readable($location)) {
   return;
 }

 require_once $location;

 });
?>
```